# Не применяется bootstrap класс .form-text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, form, layout

коллеги.
Делаю форму с использованием бустрапа 5.2.2.
Хочу сделать под инпутом текст, описывающий инпут. В [документации](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eSGk.png) бутстрапа указано, что можно использовать класс .form-text.
Но я не могу понять, почему у меня он не применяется.

Мой код:

```html
<div class="container" data-basic-container>
  <form>
    <div class="mb-3 row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="inputPassword5" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword5" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock">
        <div id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text">
          Your password must be 8-20 characters long, contain letters and numbers, and must not contain spaces, special characters, or emoji.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        Test bootstrap modules
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Мне нужно вот так:  [image: пример из документации]

А вот как выглядит у меня на локальном сервере: [image: как выглядит у меня на локальном сервере]

Comment: Будет неплохо если вы добавите сам бутстрап в сниппет.

Comment: решение нашел сам: нужно было переделать импорт бустрапа

Comment: Можете в принципе отправить как ответ, если это было решением, только постарайтесь подробней описать что именно вам помогло и как это воспроизвести.